# SSL certificate issue with nodejs application

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have developed a web application in nodejs and used selfsigned ssl certificate for testing the application. Now I have to deploy it in a server and replace the self-signed certificates with the original certificates. In the server machine at /etc/ssl/certs location there are ca.crt, server.pem file. I have generated a key.pem file and copied all three files to a folder and used them in my code as follows

```
var options =   {
              ca: fs.readFileSync('./certs/ca.crt','utf8'),
              key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/key.pem','utf8'),
              cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/server.pem','utf8')
            };
var https_server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(3003);

https_server.listen(3003,function(){
    console.log("Listening to HTTPS server on port " + 3003);
});
```

I get the following error on doing so

```
node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
at errnoException (net.js:646:11)
at Array.0 (net.js:747:26)
at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)
```

Please help!

Comment: That just means something is already listening on port `3003`. It's probably another instance of your node script. You could try killing it, before running the new version.

Comment: also slightly off-topic but you can use nginx to handle all these kinds of stuff if you want , so that multiple nodejs applications can be deployed while nginx as reverse proxy figures out these stuff.

Comment: Thank you @Paulpro. I have killed the existing process and started the application again. Now it starts without any error and the log "Listening to HTTPS server on port 3003" also appears. But when I access the application via the browser, I get the error "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". How do I debug this error?